# preg_replace insade paragprah add anchor link

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to convert insade paragraphs text into anchore link.

```
$change = array(
    'google' => 'www.google.com',
    'facebook' => 'www.facebook.com',
);

$text = "
    <h1>Search on google for facebook</h1>
    <p>Search on google for facebook</p>
";

foreach ($change as $word => $url) {
    $sentence = preg_replace('@(?<=\W|^)('.$word.')(?=\W|$)@i', '<a href="'.$url.'">$1</a>', $text);
}
echo $sentence;
```

I want to this resolute:

```
<h1>Search on google for facebook</h1>
<p>Search on <a href="www.google.com">google</a> for <a href="www.facebook.com">facebook</a></p>
```

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/j9XqSd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to match `p` tags first and perform all the replacements inside a `preg_replace_callback` anonymous function:

```
$change = array(
    'google' => 'www.google.com',
    'facebook' => 'www.facebook.com',
);

$text = "
    <h1>Search on google for facebook</h1>
    <p>Search on google for facebook</p>
";

$sentence = preg_replace_callback('~(<p\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(</p>)~s', function($m) use ($change) {
        return $m[1] . preg_replace(
              array_map(function ($x) { return '@(?<=\W|^)('.preg_quote($x, "@").')(?=\W|$)@i'; }, array_keys($change)),
              array_map(function ($y) { return '<a href="'. $y .'">$1</a>'; }, array_values($change)),
              $m[2]). $m[3]; }
, $text);

echo $sentence;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/j9XqSd).

Comment: It is possible to make only once link in paragraph. Examole if is <p>Search on google for facebook facebook</p>
If is in paragraph two time facebook it make 2 link, It is possible to make onli once?